# Any java markdown library favor github syntax?

Tags: java, github, markdown

I am looking for a java library for rendering [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) file which favor the [github markdown syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown).

Specifically I need it supports github's code block style (not supported in standard markdown):

````
```javascript
alert("hello world")
```
````

Comment: Could you elaborate? your question just too short

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Markdown to HTML with Java/Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784525/markdown-to-html-with-java-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up choosing https://code.google.com/p/markdown4j/ in my project https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm-website which is running at http://rythmengine.org/

Comment: Why did you choose that one? We're evaluating markdown processors at the moment and I'd be curious to know if there were any particular pros and cons that swayed you.

Comment: Well it's simple to use and meet my requirement, say support github extension to markdown

Answer (score 13):

You might look at https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown it appears to have some support for the GitHub flavor - including code blocks.

Comment: thanks I give you an up vote while I keep this question open for while to see if there are more options :)

Comment: Any more info about the subject?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rjeschke/txtmark is easy to use and seems to be actively developed recently. It supports many extensions to the original Markdown language - like code blocks.